Converting string to Date format using the To_Date() function
I have column of date in a table and its data-type is string. Tried to convert it to Date data-type using the function to_date() in IICS using the Expression Transformation. Values are,

1/5/2023
2/2/2023
25/11/2023
3/4/2023
12/12/2023
14/11/2023
9/5/2023

In this 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 7th value are converted, remaining values are not converted. And it throws TT_11132 Transformation error. The error message I got is

"Error message is [<> [TO_DATE]: invalid string
for converting to Date ...
t:TO_DATE(u:TO_CHAR(t:TO_DATE(u:'1/1/20',u:'dd/mm/yyyy'),u:'dd/mm/yyyy'),u:'MM/DD/YYYY
HH24:MI:SS.US')]"

. Guys needs your help.
And also the values loaded in the DB are not correct, it was loaded as,

1/5/23
2/2/23
3/4/23
9/5/23

Tried to convert the string to Date data-type using the function to_date() in IICS using the Expression Transformation.

You can't convert strings to dates because you don't know what's the month and what's the day part. 3/4/2023 can be both a day in March and a day in April. Create a date column and fix the application which inserts data in the table. Insert a date rather than a string.

What is your actual desired result?  Starting simple, this works: select to_date('25/11/2023','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual

You may be confusing how oracle renders dates with the actual date stored in the database. WFM: https://dbfiddle.uk/IiiEMq-N

Your error message states the code you are using is:
t:TO_DATE(
  u:TO_CHAR(
    t:TO_DATE(
      u:'1/1/20',
      u:'dd/mm/yyyy'
    ),
    u:'dd/mm/yyyy'
  ),
  u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US'
)

Don't convert the value from a string to a date then back to a string and then back to a date. The last two transformations are pointless as you already had the value as a date.
Especially don't change the format model you are using so that you convert it to a string in the format dd/mm/yyyy and then back to a date using the format model MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US because the string is not in that format and you are trying to read days-as-months and vice versa (which is what is causing your error).
If you want to convert a string in the format dd/mm/yyyy to a date then use:
TO_DATE(your_column, 'dd/mm/yyyy')

